# Integrating Scrapy with Django 1.9 : django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: django, scrapy

I am trying to use Scrapy along with Django 1.9. Both Django project 'JobEngine' and Scrapy project 'computer_jobs_nepal' are within same directory. I have set the Scrapy settings.py file to locate Django models. I think importing django models in items.py file is working well. But I run my spider :

```
 scrapy crawl jobsdetail
```

It raises following error:

```
       File "......../Django1/computer_jobs_nepal/computer_jobs_nepal/spiders/job_detail_spider.py", line 5, in <module>

       from computer_jobs_nepal.items import ComputerJobsNepalItem

       File "........../Django1/computer_jobs_nepal/computer_jobs_nepal/items.py", line 18, in <module>

       from apps.jobmanager.models import Job

       File "........./Django1/JobEngine/JobEngine/apps/jobmanager/models.py", line 18, in <module>

       class Job(models.Model):

       File "......../envdjango/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 94, in __new__

       app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)

       File "........./envdjango/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 239, in get_containing_app_config

       self.check_apps_ready()

       File "........./envdjango/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready

       raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
       django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to have following inside your scrapy settings.py file to have django integrated.

```
import sys
...

sys.path.append('/path/to/your/django_project')
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: I have included 

  `  from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application`
  ` application = get_wsgi_application()`

Inside scrapy settings file. Now, I am getting  raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.

Comment: You probably do not have it in path I'm just edit answer